# Bad Substitution error with pdfgrep as variable?

Tags: bash, grep

I'm using a bash script to parse information from a PDF and use it to rename the file (with the help of pdfgrep). However, after some working, I'm receiving a "Bad Substitution" error with line 5. Any ideas on how to reformat it?

```
shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob
for f in *.pdf; do
    id1=$(pdfgrep -i "ID #: " "$f" | grep -oE "[M][0-9][0-9]+")
    id2=$(pdfgrep -i "Second ID: " "$f" | grep -oE "[V][0-9][0-9]+")
    $({ read dobmonth; read dobday; read dobyear; } < (pdfgrep -i "Date Of Birth: " "$f" | grep -oE "[0-9]+"))
    # Check id1 is found, else do nothing
    if [ ${#id1} ]; then
       mv "$f" "${id1}_${id2}_${printf '%02d-%02d-%04d\n' "$dobmonth" "$dobday" "$dobyear"}.pdf"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Maybe you mean `< <(...)`? The current construction of `< (...)` isn't valid/meaningful syntax.

Comment: Even with that change, though, your code won't be meaningfully useful: `$(...)` puts its contents in a subshell, so the values you assign to `dobmonth` won't persist past the subshell's exit and thus won't be available for the subsequent `mv`.

Comment: ...and `${printf ...}` isn't useful/meaningful either.

Comment: The problem is that the date it copies is in the wrong format, so I'm attempting to copy the series of numbers that pdfgrep returns and reformat it with leading zeros if the date/month is a single digit.

Comment: The concerns raised above are about syntax, not intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several unrelated bugs in this code; a corrected version might look like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob
for f in *.pdf; do
    id1=$(pdfgrep -i "ID #: " "$f" | grep -oE "[M][0-9][0-9]+") || continue
    id2=$(pdfgrep -i "Second ID: " "$f" | grep -oE "[V][0-9][0-9]+") || continue
    { read dobmonth; read dobday; read dobyear; } < <(pdfgrep -i "Date Of Birth: " "$f" | grep -oE "[0-9]+")
    printf -v date '%02d-%02d-%04d' "$dobmonth" "$dobday" "$dobyear"
    mv -- "$f" "${id1}_${id2}_${date}.pdf"
done
```

- `< (...)` isn't meaningful bash syntax. If you want to redirect from a [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst), you should use the redirection syntax `<` and the process substitution `<(...)` separately.
- `$(...)` generates a subshell -- a separate process with its own memory, such that variables assigned in that subprocess aren't exposed to the larger shell as a whole. Consequently, if you want the contents you set with `read` to be visible, you can't have them be in a subshell.
- `${printf ...}` isn't meaningful syntax. Perhaps you wanted a command substitution? That would be `$(printf ...)`, not `${printf ...}`. However, it's more efficient to use `printf -v varname 'fmt' ...`, which avoids the overhead of forking off a subshell altogether.
- Because we put the `|| continue`s on the `id1=$(... | grep ...)` command, we no longer need to test whether `id1` is nonempty: The `continue` will trigger and cause the shell to continue to the next file should the `grep` fail.

Answer (score 0):

Do what Charles suggests wrt creating the new file name but you might consider a different approach to parsing the PDF file to reduce how many pdfregs and pipes and greps you're doing on each file. I don't have pdfgrep on my system, nor do I know what your input file looks like but if we use this input file:

```
$ cat file
foo
ID #: M13
foo
Date Of Birth: 05 21 1996
foo
Second ID: V27
foo
```

and `grep -E` in place of `pdfgrep` then here's how I'd get the info from the input file by just reading it once with `pdfgrep` and parsing that output with `awk` instead of reading it multiple times with `pdfgrep` and using multiple pipes and `greps` to extract the info you need:

```
$ grep -E -i '(ID #|Second ID|Date Of Birth): ' file |
awk -F': +' '{f[$1]=$2} END{print f["ID #"], f["Second ID"], f["Date Of Birth"]}'
M13 V27 05 21 1996
```

Given that you can use the same `read` approach to save the output in variables (or an array). You obviously may need to massage the awk command depending on what your `pdfgrep` output actually looks like.